# Isabelle confused by a previous lemma?

Tags: debugging, isabelle

I found something strange while doing exercise 2.5 of the Concrete Semantics book. Basically, we have to prove the famous Gauss formula for the sum n integers. Here is my code:

```
fun sum_upto :: "nat ⇒ nat" where
"sum_upto 0 = 0" |
"sum_upto (Suc n) = (Suc n) + (sum_upto n)"

lemma gauss: "sum_upto n = (n * (n + 1)) div 2"
apply(induction n)
apply(auto)
done
```

This won't proceed at least I remove a previous lemma from exercise 2.3:

```
fun double :: "nat ⇒ nat" where
"double 0 = 0" |
"double (Suc n) = add (double n) 2"

lemma double_succ [simp]: "Suc (Suc (m)) = add m 2"
apply(induction m)
apply(auto)
done

lemma double_add: "double m = add m m"
apply(induction m)
apply(auto)
done
```

So here add is a user-defined function for addition. I've looked other solutions and my definition of double is substituted by `Suc(Suc (double n))` in that case, the next lemma is unnecessary and the error in Gauss disappears.

However, I'm interested to know why is this happening because in principle both problems don't use any common structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[simp]` is at fault here. Try removing it and see if that helps.

The underlying reason is that `[simp]` will add a rule to the so-called *simpset* and will be used by the `simp`, `auto`, etc. methods automatically. Great care needs to be taken before lemmas are declared as `[simp]` because of that.

In your case, the problem is that `Suc (Suc m) = add m 2` is not a good rule for the simpset. It will replace all instances of `Suc (Suc m)` with `add m 2`, which is probably the opposite direction of what you want.

Comment: isn't it the definition of double you're looking for at the beginning of the second snippet of code? many thanks for your answer i'll experiment with it

Comment: curiously, without removing the simp (in principle I need it to prove a previous lemma) but inversing the order of the lemma to add m 2 = Succ (Succ m) does the trick

Comment: Right, I somehow overlooked that definition. And yes, your other solution would also work.